# Escaping string with quotes in test

Tags: string, escaping

Hi in java I have following output string.

```
{"option" : "\"optionA\""}
```

Now I need to check if another string contains above value with .contains method. How can I check for above string, there is some issue with escaping characters.

```
sample.contains(response.contains("\{\"option\":\"\\\"optionA\\\"\"\}");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the problem here with redundant backslashes before curly brackets.
Symbol "{" should not be avoided, because it can be interpreted as a part of string. This should work:

```
sample.contains(response.contains("{\"option\":\"\\\"optionA\\\"\"}");
```